# Checkbox value changes when sorting array in vue + vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In vue + vuetify, I have multiple checkboxes linked to an array for v-model. Problem is when I sort the array it loops on, the values of the checkboxes change which is not behavior I want. I want it's value to be preserved. Here is an example

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/BaWPQmP?editors=101

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container class="px-0" fluid>
            <v-btn @click="FullRefresh" color="primary">
                <v-icon>refresh</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <div v-for="g in todos">
                <v-checkbox v-model="selected" :value="g.id" :disabled="true" :label="g.text"></v-checkbox>
            </div>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      checkbox: true,
      selected:[1,3],
          todos: [
            { id:1, text: "Learn JavaScript", val: 6 },
            { id:2, text: "Learn Vue", val: 4 },
            { id:3, text: "Play around in JSFiddle", val: 2 },
            { id:4, text: "Build something awesome", val: 1 }
          ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    FullRefresh:function() {
      this.todos = this.todos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.val - b.val;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

In the demo, just click the refresh button, and it sorts the array. See how all checkboxes become checked somehow....

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: On a side note; you don’t have to assign the sorted array to ‘todos’. The array is sorted in place. You can easily debug by console logging the ‘selected’ array after you sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `v-for`, you should always use `key`

```html
<div v-for="g in todos" :key="g.id">
```

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index.

> this default mode is efficient, **but only suitable when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM state (e.g. form input values).**